# How to add ellipsis in GitHub commits?

Tags: git, github

I've seen a commit history where someone pushed commit which had an ellipsis to expand the commit message.

I want to add that ellipsis for my commits and I have no idea how to do that.

I tried to search solution of my requirement on Stack Overflow but found nothing.

Comment: You mean in the GitHub web UI? It shows that for any commit message that's more than just a title.

Comment: This question does not lack “details or clarity”. It is confused in a very obvious way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A commit message can be formed as two parts from the command line with the use of multiple `-m` entries

`git commit -m 'a title' -m 'a full body message'`

> -m <msg>
> --message=<msg>
> Use the given  as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.
> The -m option is mutually exclusive with -c, -C, and -F.

src: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--mltmsggt

The same can be done with a GUI git client which offers a title and the commit message body.

Comment: Good tip, but I'm not sure it answers the question of expanding commit messages. Are you suggesting that GitHub automatically collapses subsequent paragraphs?

Comment: This is an X answer to an XY question.

Comment: considering they are using github and you can assume the web interface, it's likely this is what the OP was looking for.